# Why does memcpy into a buffer and a pointer to the buffer work the same?

Tags: c, string, pointers, buffer, memcpy

Say I have the following code:

```
char buff[100] = {0};
char msg[] = "hello!";

memcpy(buff, msg, sizeof(msg));

OR

memcpy(&buff, msg, sizeof(msg));
```

Why do the two memcpy lines work exactly the same?

I expected that when &buff is used, it would copy the msg into the memory where the pointer itself that buff decays into is stored, not the memory that that pointer actually points to.

When I imagine the pointers like this:

`&buff->buff->buff[0]`

I can rationalize why they behave the same. But when I imagine the actual memory like this:

```
address        | value   | (name)
--------------  --------- ----------------
0x1000         | 'h'     | (buff[0])
0x1001         | 'e'     | (buff[1])
... etc
__________________________________________

0x5000-0x5008  | 0x1000  | (buf - char *)
__________________________________________

0x8000-0x8008  | 0x5000  | (&buf - char**)
__________________________________________
```

Now I cannot see why the msg is not written at address 0x5000 instead, overwriting the value 0x1000.

Comment: `&buff` is the address of the array itself, `buff` decays to the address of the first element of the array. They are the same address in memory but different pointer types.

Comment: First line in the documentation. `Copies count bytes from the object **pointed** to by src to the object **pointed** to by dest. Both objects are reinterpreted as arrays of unsigned char.`

Comment: `&buff` is not of type `char **`, it’s type is `char (*)[100]`. And while the types are different, the actual values of the pointers passed to `mempy()` are the same in either case. `buff` decays to `char *` when it’s passed to `memcpy()`, not before, so `&buff` is not the address of the decayed pointer.

Comment: `memcpy` will convert the pointers to `void *`. If you call `printf("%p, %p\n", (void *)&buff, (void *)buff);` you should see the same `void *` pointer value printed twice (at least on architectures that use "flat" pointers).

Comment: When an array is used in most expressions, it is converted to a pointer to the first element. The exceptions are when it is the operand of the unary `&` operator, or the `sizeof` operator, or the `typeof` or `typeof_unqual` operators (for C23), (or the `alignof` operator, although that is not mentioned in the same place in the standard as the others). `&buff` is one of those exceptions.

Comment: (Ignore the bit about `alignof` in my comment above. I was thinking that `alignof` allowed its operand to be a unary expression like `sizeof` does, but that was incorrect; it's operand must be a type name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.3.2.1 3 says an array is converted to a pointer to its first element except when:

- it is the operand of `sizeof`,
- it is the operand of unary `&`, or
- it is a string literal used to initialize an array.

So, in `memcpy(&buff, msg, sizeof(msg))`, `buff` is the operand of unary `&` and is not converted to a pointer. `&buff` gives a pointer to the array.

In `memcpy(buff, msg, sizeof(msg))`, `buff` is converted to a pointer to its first element.

The starting location of the first element and the starting location of the array are the same location. So `&buff` and `buff` have the same value, but different types. So data is copied to the same place in both calls.

(Also note that the difference in types becomes irrelevant because the first parameter of `memcpy` is declared to be `void * restrict`, so both `&buff` and `buff` are converted to the same type before the call.)

Answer (score 2):

> Why do the two `memcpy` lines work exactly the same?

The address of an array and the address of the first element of the array point to the same location.

---

`memcpy(buff, msg, sizeof(msg));` is like `memcpy(&buff[0], msg, sizeof(msg));` as the array `buff` converts to the type and a pointer to the first element of the array in this usage.  Then that pointer to the first element of the array is converted to a `void *`.

So we are really comparing `(void *) &buff[0]` and `(void *) &buff`.

---

> I expected that when `&buff` is used, it would copy the `msg` into the memory where the pointer itself that `buff` decays into is stored,

No.  `&buff` is a pointer and the *value* of that pointer is passed into `memcpy()`.  There is no *decay* going on with `&buff`. The unary `&` operator is one of the exceptions to the rule that arrays decay to pointers to their first element in expressions. The other exceptions are when an array is the operand of the `sizeof`, `typeof`, or `typeof_unqual` operators (as of C23).

Comment: "There is no *decay* going on with `&buff`." I think that is the key to OP's misunderstanding, and it may be worth explaining that unary `&` is one of the exceptions where arrays do not decay.

Comment: @IanAbbott I agree.  Feel free to edit this wiki answer.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it does not decay is exactly what I was missing. I forgot that it is one of the exceptions. Thank you!